# In a ring with no nilpotent elements (0) is not decomposable.

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra

This question has two parts

1. I came out with this conjecture in the title: In a ring with no nilpotent elements (0) is not decomposable, and I think I have a proof of it:

> Since the ring has no nilpotent elements we now that $ \sqrt{0}=0$ so $ 0$ has no minimal prime ideals belonging to 0. The minimal prime ideals belonging to zero are precisely the minimal prime ideals of the ring. Since every ring has minimal prime ideals $0 $ cannot be decomposable.

Is this proof right?

2. I want to prove that in the ring $C(X)$ the set of continuous real valued functions of $f$ on $X$, a Compact Hausdorff space, 0 is not decomposable. A proof of this can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164888/example-of-non-decomposable-ideal). Using my previous "proof" I came up with this alternative proof:

> the maximal ideals are of the form $M_c=\{f:f(c)=0\}$. Since the set of nilpotent elements is a subset of the Jacobson Radical = $\bigcap_{c\in \mathbb{R}}M_c =0$ we have that  0 is not decomposable.

I think that my proof is not ok since I'm not using the Hausdorff hypothesis which I think is important. The compactness is used in the claim "the maximal ideals are of the form $ M_c$" can some one point out what is wrong?

Thank you all in advance

**Note:**
When I  post questions of the type "what is wrong here"  is so common to get answers of the type "your proof is wrong since the conclusion is wrong" which for me is equivalent to say "your proof is wrong because it is wrong". The kind of answer I'm looking for is "your proof is wrong because in this specific part of your proof you are wrong" so please avoid the first kind of answers.

**Note 2**

An ideal $I$ is decomposable if there are $Q_1,⋯,Q_m$ primary ideals such that I=⋂Qi. The $\sqrt{Q_i}$ are said to **belong** to I. Note that it is not necessarily true that $\sqrt{Q_i} \subseteq I $ nevertheless we still say it **belongs** to $ I$.

Comment: Isn’t $F_2\times F_2$ already a counterexample to #1?

Comment: Isn’t the point that sometimes the zero ideal requires infinitely many primary ideals in its decomposition? Because it is *always* the intersection of a family of prime ideals in a reduced ring.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence of your proof is already false; in an integral domain we have $\sqrt{0}=0$, but $0$ is a minimal prime ideal belonging to $0$.

Comment: Saying that $ 0$ is always an ideal belonging to zero is to say that $0$ is always decomposable isn't it?

Comment: What is your definition of *decomposable*?

Comment: An ideal $I$ is decomposable if  there are $Q_1,\cdots, Q_m $ primamry ideals such that $I=\bigcap Q_i $. The $Q_i $ are said to belong to $ I$.

Comment: Then no, the zero ideal is not always decomposable. The question you link to gives an example of a ring where it isn't. I've revised my answer to be more to the point.

Comment: Yes I know it is not, in fact the second part of my question is trying to prove the opposite, but if you say $0$ always belongs to $0$ you are intrinsically saying that zero is decomposable.

Comment: No, I am not. Any ideal belongs to itself, and in particular $0$ belongs to $0$. The linked question gives a clear example of a ring where $0$ is not decomposable. Could you explain how you think one implies the other?

Comment: It implies the other because the prime ideals belonging to $ I$ are by definition the radicals of the primary ideals in a decomposition.

Comment: Ah, we seem to use 'belonging to' in a different way then. Never mind this discussion then, see my revised answer for a refutal of the first sentence of your proof.

Comment: I know "belong" is a bad word for that, but it is the way they used it in Atiyah-MacDonald. Thank you any way.